# Para que serve a linguagem Fortran?

Tags: característica-linguagem, fortran

Em quais ocasiões, nos dias atuais, se usa a linguagem Fortran? Qual é seu ponto forte e sua finalidade?

Comment: Essa, junto com a sua pergunta [Como surgiu a linguagem Assembly e quem foi seu criador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/335563/5878), parece ser de uma lista de exercício e não exatamente dúvidas. Se assim for, talvez não tenha entendido bem como o site funciona. Leia o guia de [ask] para ver como elaborar uma boa pergunta.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

Serve para o mesmo que as outras linguagens de alto nível, ela permite que um humano escreva algoritmo de tal forma que depois de interpretado por algum aplicativo (compilador ou interpretador) se transforme em instruções que a máquina entende e execute esse algoritmo produzindo resultados computacionais.

Como ela foi a primeira linguagem de alto nível a ser criada seu principal trunfo era permitir uma foma mais fácil e simples de escrever códigos evitando alguns erros que eram muito comuns em Assembly.

Como o início da computação só importava cálculos, ela foi pensada em facilitar isso e até hoje ela é vista como forte em manipulações numéricas complexas, principalmente com vetores de dados. Hoje ela possui várias otimizações para isto e por ter limitações em outros pontos pode focar nessa parte.

Claro que ela faz várias outras coisas como qualquer linguagem de programação, mas é muito boa nisto e chega ser mais rápida que C em algumas operações. E não tem as idiossincrasias de tratamento de mecanismos que C tem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Perfeito! Valeu!